# Skipping an if statement from inside and skip to next

Tags: c++

I have an `if` statement.  If the check equals to what I want, I want to continue to another `if` statement.

```
  else if (HasStaticRealAngle(cur))
  {
        if (Global::bulletresolver[player->EntIndex()].missedbullets >= 1)
        //skip to next statement
        new_yaw = 32;
  }
  else
    new_yaw = 10;
```

I've commented where I want to skip to the `else`.

Comment: Sorry my English is bad what I want to do is have the if statement then inside check the bullets and if the bullets are above 1 or equal it will skip to the else

Comment: Have you considered simply reversing the condition, and placing the instruction in the `if`'s body? "Skip the next instruction if and only if my condition is true" is equivalent to "Execute the next instruction if and only if my condition is false".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `new_yaw` to `10` when `missedbullets >= 1`, then you can combine the two checks into a single `if` statement using the `&&` operator:

```
else if (HasStaticRealAngle(cur) && (Global::bulletresolver[player->EntIndex()].missedbullets < 1))
    new_yaw = 32;
else
    new_yaw = 10;
```

Comment: From the description, it should probably be `if (!HasStaticRealAngle(cur) || (Global::bulletresolver[player->EntIndex()].missedbullets < 1)) new_yaw = 10; else new_yaw = 32;`

Comment: @scohe001: almost. You need to use `>=` instead of `<`.  The OP clearly stated that the `else` (ie `new_yaw=10`) should be used when "*the bullets are above 1 or equal*". Whether you use your code or mine, the end result of `new_yaw` will be the same

Comment: Ahhh I missed your `<`. That was some sneaky DeMorgan's. Well played.